# Reading shared variables with relaxed ordering: is it possible in theory? Is it possible in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-model

Consider the following pseudocode:

```
expected = null;
if (variable == expected)
{
    atomic_compare_exchange_strong(
        &variable, expected, desired(), memory_order_acq_rel, memory_order_acq);
}
return variable;
```

Observe there are *no* "acquire" semantics when the `variable == expected` check is performed.

It seems to me that `desired` will be called at least once in total, and at most *once* per thread.
Furthermore, if `desired` never returns `null`, *then this code will **never** return `null`*.

Now, I have three questions:

1. Is the above necessarily true? i.e., can we really have well-ordered reads of shared variables even in the absence of fences on every read?
2. Is it possible to implement this in C++? If so, how? If not, why?
   (Hopefully with a rationale, not just "because the standard says so".)
3. If the answer to (2) is yes, then is it also possible to implement this in C++ **without** requiring `variable == expected` to perform an *atomic* read of `variable`?

Basically, my goal is to understand if it is possible to perform lazy-initialization of a shared variable in a manner that has performance *identical* to that of a non-shared variable once the code has been executed at least once by each thread?

(This is somewhat of a "language-lawyer" question. So that implies the question isn't about whether this is a good or useful idea, but rather about whether it's technically possible to do this correctly.)

Comment: @nosid: No. See #3. The question is also about whether or not atomicity is required at all, regardless of memory ordering issues.

Comment: @nosid: I didn't mention it because the first thing I mentioned is that this is pseudocode, so don't expect it to be valid C++. The focus is on the concept; C++ is just one aspect of the overall question.

Comment: So, what if `variable` is large so that `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` has to use a mutex? You'd try to access `variable == expected` while the object is being changed, which means that e.g. its class invariants don't have to hold.

Comment: The pseudo code has little meaning without a memory model to describe how multi-threaded reads/writes work.  C++11 has a memory model, but your pseudo-code is not C++, as C++ variables have types, and those types impact how they behave under the C++11 memory model.

Comment: @Yakk: I hesitate to use the C++ memory model because most of the question is conceptual, not C++ specific. Only part of it asks if this could be achieved in C++, and for that section, you can give the variables whatever types you deem appropriate to make it work. Can you imagine this failing on *any* (sane) memory model with a convincing rationale (i.e. not just because "the memory model says so" but rather *why* it might say so)?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the question whether it is possible to perform lazy initialisation of a shared variable in C++, that has a performance (almost) identical to that of a non-shared variable:

The answer is, that it depends on the hardware architecture, and the implementation of the compiler and run-time environment. At least, it is possible in some environments. In particular on x86 with GCC and Clang.

On x86, atomic reads can be implemented without memory fences. Basically, an atomic read is identical to a non-atomic read. Take a look at the following compilation unit:

```
std::atomic<int> global_value;
int load_global_value() { return global_value.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst); }
```

Although I used an atomic operation with *sequential consistency* (the default), there is nothing special in the generated code. The assembler code generated by GCC and Clang looks as follows:

```
load_global_value():
    movl global_value(%rip), %eax
    retq
```

I said *almost* identical, because there are other reasons that might impact the performance. For example:

- although there is no fence, the atomic operations still prevent some compiler optimisations, e.g. reordering instructions and elimination of stores and loads
- if there is at least one thread, that writes to a different memory location on the same cache line, it will have a huge impact on the performance (known as *false sharing*)

Having said that, the recommended way to implement lazy initialisation is to use `std::call_once`. That should give you the best result for all compilers, environments and target architectures.

```
std::once_flag _init;
std::unique_ptr<gadget> _gadget;

auto get_gadget() -> gadget&
{
    std::call_once(_init, [this] { _gadget.reset(new gadget{...}); });
    return *_gadget;
}
```

Comment: +1 although this isn't the direction I was going. I wasn't trying to ask an architecture-specific question; I was wondering if I could be sure that this could be done on *all* architectures, assuming they implemented `atomic_compare_and_swap_strong` in a sane fashion. The real question is why an unprotected read might be insufficient on some architectures, *not* whether a particular architecture might be able to do it.

Comment: @Mehrdad The `std::call_once` is guaranteed to work on all platforms.  And the statement "On x86, atomic reads can be implemented without memory fences" isn't really true; the processor can reorder reads (but not, I think, writes, at least with older processors).

Comment: @James: yes but neither of those answers my question. My question was neither about call_once more about a specific architecture like x86.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Are you sure about the reorderings? As I said, both Clang and GCC use an ordinary load. The following page on Wikipedia also created the impression, that loads can not be reordered (as long as we are not talking about ancient machines): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering

Comment: @nosid Intel is certainly less permissive than processors like the Sparc and the Alpha, but it definitely allows some reordering, see http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf.  (More importantly, perhaps: the ordering guarantees have been loosed once in the past, so one can assume that they will be loosened again in the future.)

Comment: @nosid Of course, the real point is that if you use the synchronization primitives of the standard, you're guaranteed, period.  It's up to the authors of your compiler to ensure that it works as specified.

Comment: What can possible go wrong? dyp made an example in the comments. Why was the memory model defined as it is? Most likely because the committee tried to find a solution that is good both for the implementers and the users of the language. See the following link for some arguments by Hans Boehm: http://www.hboehm.info/c++mm/why_undef.html

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior.  You're modifying `variable`, at
least in some thread, which means that *all* accesses to
variable must be protected.  In particular, when you're
executing the `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` in one thread,
there is nothing to guarantee that another thread might see the
new value of `variable` before it sees the writes that might
have occurred in `desired()`.  (`atomic_compare_exchange_strong`
only guarantees any ordering in the thread that executes it.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you worried about memory writes that `desired` might have performed? Would your answer change if `desired` didn't perform any memory writes, and instead just returned a value that was significant on its own? (say it was returning an integer instead of a pointer, or say `desired` had a memory barrier inside that ensured everything is visible before it returned.) Furthermore, the crux of the question is, *why* should every access be protected? Wouldn't *not* protecting the read of `variable` still result in correct code, because of the compare and swap later?

Comment: There's not really much to understand.  If an object may be accessed in more than one thread, and you modify it in any thread, then _all_ accesses to it must be synchronized, or you have undefined behavior.  The issue concerning writes in `desired` was just an example of the sort of things that can go wrong.

Comment: I'm not asking what can go wrong (which is what the standard says), rather I'm asking *why* it could go wrong (the rationale behind what the standard might say). So I don't understand what could possibly go wrong in this code for any other reason than "because the standard says so".

Comment: @Mehrdad Why it could go wrong is simple: modern processors reorder how reads and writes appear on the external bus, to different degrees, depending on the processor.  All of them have various fence or membar instructions to guarantee the order, when it is needed.  Your code is basically a variant of double-checked locking, which has been proven unsafe without additional hardware synchronization on the load in the `if`.

Comment: No, I think this is different from double checked locking, at least the typical kind. There is no other location of memory that is shared here, but in double checked locking a new object is constructed whose initialization needs to happen after the variable is written to, so the relative ordering is an issue there. Correct?

Comment: @Mehrdad It's subtly different, but the same basic principles apply.  (Except maybe if `desired()` returns a constant, in which case you could probably just use static initialization and be done with it.)

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the same basic principles apply? It's an assertion I simply don't see any support for, because any valid re-ordering I can think of simply *cannot* affect the correctness if there is no 2nd memory location whose ordering we need to worry about compared to this one. Regarding the constant case, it may very well be expensive to compute the constant (maybe we need to read it from a file or the network?), so we might want to avoid it unless we really need to -- static initialization isn't necessarily a substitute.

Comment: (... unless you mean *local* static initialization. But there's no reason the constant has to be the same across the entire program either. Maybe the variable's value will depend on its own address (say, maybe we want a pseudorandom seed per object, and generating the pseudorandom seed is expensive so we want to avoid it)... again, the point is there are reasons we might want to do this that don't necessarily have substitutes, but I don't want to get sidetracked on that.)